# PHP - combining multiple variables into 1 and then echoing them

Tags: php, html, variables

So I'll explain what I mean with code:

```
$sub_content_1 = "<h2>View files</h2><br><ul><li><p>";

$var = rand(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
if ($var == 1){
print '<a href="/dir1/file1">link1</a>';
}
if ($var == 2){
print '<a href="/dir2/file2">link2</a>';
}
if ($var == 3){
print '<a href="/dir3/file3">link3</a>';
}
if ($var == 4){
print '<a href="/dir4/file4">link4</a>';
}
if ($var == 5){
print '<a href="/dir5/file5">link5</a>';
}
if ($var == 6){
print '<a href="/dir6/file6">link6</a>';
}
if ($var == 7){
print '<a href="/dir7/file7">link7</a>';
}
if ($var == 8){
print '<a href="/dir8/file8">link8</a>';
}
if ($var == 9){
print '<a href="/dir9/file9">link9</a>';
}
if ($var == 10){
print '<a href="/dir10/file10">link10</a>';
}

$sub_content_2 = "</p></li></ul><br><button type=\"button\" onclick=\"window.location.href='/files';\">View All</button>";
```

And now I need to unite the 3 vars:

```
$content = "sub_content_1 + sub_content_2 + the printed value of $var"

echo "$content";
```

Desired result:

[HTML MARKUP FROM `$sub_content_1`]

[HTML MARKUP FROM `$var`]

[HTML MARKUP FROM `$sub_content_2`]

How to achieve this?

Comment: `$var = rand(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
print '<a href="/dir'.$var.'/file'.$var.'">link'.$var.'</a>';` rather than that mass of `if` tests

Comment: Check my edited answer out, thats what you want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $sub_content_1 = "<h2>View files</h2><br><ul><li><p>";

    $var = rand(1,10);
    if ($var == 1){
    $var = '<a href="/dir1/file1">link1</a>';
    print '<a href="/dir1/file1">link1</a>';
    }
    if ($var == 2){
$var = '<a href="/dir2/file2">link2</a>';
    print '<a href="/dir2/file2">link2</a>';
    }
    if ($var == 3){
$var = '<a href="/dir3/file3">link3</a>';
    print '<a href="/dir3/file3">link3</a>';
    }
    if ($var == 4){
    $var = '<a href="/dir4/file4">link4</a>';
    print '<a href="/dir4/file4">link4</a>';
    }
    if ($var == 5){
$var = '<a href="/dir5/file5">link5</a>';
    print '<a href="/dir5/file5">link5</a>';
    }
    if ($var == 6){
    $var = '<a href="/dir6/file6">link6</a>';
    print '<a href="/dir6/file6">link6</a>';
    }
    if ($var == 7){
    $var = '<a href="/dir7/file7">link7</a>';
    print '<a href="/dir7/file7">link7</a>';
    }
    if ($var == 8){
    $var = '<a href="/dir8/file8">link8</a>';
    print '<a href="/dir8/file8">link8</a>';
    }
    if ($var == 9){
$var =  '<a href="/dir9/file9">link9</a>';
    print '<a href="/dir9/file9">link9</a>';
    }
    if ($var == 10){
    $var =  '<a href="/dir10/file10">link10</a>';
    print '<a href="/dir10/file10">link10</a>';
    }

    $sub_content_2 = "</p></li></ul><br><button type=\"button\" onclick=\"window.location.href='/files';\">View All</button>";

    $content = $sub_content_1 . $sub_content_2 . $var;
    echo $content;
```

the dot '.' is combining variables in PHP. In javascript it is the '+'

Comment: I know that but when I add `$var` to the code it will print a random number from 1-10 not the value I want to print. That value is printed on top of the page.

Comment: you assigned the `$val` a random number on line 2 . so it will definitely print a random number

Comment: What value u want to print? $var will always print a rnadom number from 1-10 $var = rand(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

Comment: @Xatenev You're my hero! That worked like a charm. I just removed the `print` and it is OK now. Thank you for that answer.

Answer (score 0):

php function rand() accepts 2 parms . if you want to genrate a number between 1-10 then the function should be called like this `rand(1,10)`

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Online PHP Script Execution</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
   $sub_content_1 = "<h2>View files</h2><br><ul><li><p>";

$var = rand(1,10);
if ($var == 1){
print '<a href="/dir1/file1">link1</a>';
}
if ($var == 2){
print '<a href="/dir2/file2">link2</a>';
}
if ($var == 3){
print '<a href="/dir3/file3">link3</a>';
}
if ($var == 4){
print '<a href="/dir4/file4">link4</a>';
}
if ($var == 5){
print '<a href="/dir5/file5">link5</a>';
}
if ($var == 6){
print '<a href="/dir6/file6">link6</a>';
}
if ($var == 7){
print '<a href="/dir7/file7">link7</a>';
}
if ($var == 8){
print '<a href="/dir8/file8">link8</a>';
}
if ($var == 9){
print '<a href="/dir9/file9">link9</a>';
}
if ($var == 10){
print '<a href="/dir10/file10">link10</a>';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, I meant that I want to print the value of `$var`. I want to print the `a` tags.

Comment: Adding the `$var` will print a random number from 1-10. It won't print the `a` tag and its content. The `a` tag is printed outside the `html` tag for some odd reason.

Comment: @Xatenev i think PowerUser wants to print a random hyper link .